# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'isLegacyViewHelper' of undefined

Tags: ember.js

I don't have any problems when I work in local but when I use the prod, it gives me this error. I've been searching for a long time.
The error is in the script vendor.js.

Tell me if you want some code to understand. I have no idea which file I need to show.

Thanks

EDIT 1 :

```
function registerHandlebarsCompatibleHelper(name, value) {
if (value && value.isLegacyViewHelper) {
  _emberHtmlbarsKeywords.registerKeyword(name, function (morph, env, scope, params, hash, template, inverse, visitor) {
    Ember.assert("You can only pass attributes (such as name=value) not bare " + "values to a helper for a View found in '" + value.viewClass + "'", params.length === 0);

    env.hooks.keyword("view", morph, env, scope, [value.viewClass], hash, template, inverse, visitor);
    return true;
  });
  return;
}
```

Version :
Ember : 1.13.1
Ember Data : 1.13.5

Comment: Go to line in Developer Tools, find on which line in vendor.js problem is and try to copy fragment of code that is responsible for failure. Also, which version of Ember and Ember Data do you use?

Comment: When this error happens? You go to any route or something? If yes then please post template code of this route or its components, maybe there's an error there.

Comment: This error happens when the page load, at the very beginning.

Comment: Do you use old syntax for example `{{#each model as item}}` instead of `{{#each model key='id' as |item|}}`?

Comment: yes, I use {{#each model as item}} syntax, it's wrong?

Comment: It generated such errors for me. Try to refactor it.

Comment: ok, i'll try it! Thanks you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error occurs because of a mistake I make.
I forgot to include a controller before commit the project in production.

Answer (score 0):

The reason might be using old legacy syntax for example in `{{each}}` helper. Even if it should work it generated rendering errors in my application. When I refactored this to new syntax it worked. So I would suggest updating, refactoring syntax to latest standards from Ember guides and blog posts. So, basically try to use:

```
{{#each model as item}}
```

Instead of:

```
{{#each model key='id' as |item|}}
```

If this won't help you then delete your template code to help debug this. Try to narrow code that might cause these errors. For example, remove all HTMLBars code in `application.hbs`, then, see if your app works in production, if yes then delete less code in `application.hbs` and see it works or not. This way you can track down issue.